# What is a normal value of DataCacheSize can be?

Tags: c++, caching, marmalade

What is a proper value of DataCacheSize should be set in Marmalade (for example for iphone 4)?

I meen, how could I know what value is not too much for devices, as far as default 16k is really nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `DataCacheSize=1000000` value for all my published project for iOS, Android and blackberry and never got any problems. If you really want to optimise the value per project, you'll need to checkout the `view matrix` option in the simulator.